# Error on indexer

Tags: magento2.4, reindex

Currently using Magento Open Source ver 2.4.6-p2
with php 8.1, running on a shared hosting

I had uploaded a list of products (around 250 SKU) on the site and set up the index management "Update by schedule" at a 10-min interval at the moment ("Update on save" also having the same issue before)

Everyday the system will at certain time point (previously during midnight, but now at around 11am) it will only able to load 8 products in the frontend only (at the backend all items remain). All of the filter option also disappeared except Price. This will be able to fix by running the command line "bin/magento indexer:reindex", all the product will resume listing on the frontend.

Tried "bin/magento indexer:reset" but the problem persist.

Current cron job command line on the shared hosting is

> /opt/alt/php81/usr/bin/php /home/xxx/public_html/bin/magento cron:run
> 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >>
> /home/xxx/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log

In the var/log/system.log, i've found one error:

> main.WARNING: Deadlock detected in cron: SQLSTATE[40001]:
> Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock;
> try restarting transaction, query was: UPDATE `mgif_cron_schedule` SET
> `status` = ? WHERE (job_code =
> 'catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush') AND (status = 'running') []
> []

In the var/log/debug.log & cron.log, I some lines are showing "main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: ..." but those lines shouldn't be affecting the product list

So, the error found in the system.log seems the log for the error, does anyone understand about this error and how to fix the issue? I'm new on setting up magento, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

or you can follow this [link](https://www.naguel.com/magento-and-a-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock/)

Hope this will work for you :)

Comment: no, this doesn't work. problem remains

Comment: the issue is unless I do reindex manually everytime, the problem just repeating day after day

Comment: and the mentioned link also do not work, it will make the site (the indexes) into error and nothing would be loaded